Invoking static methods within Unity editor
Does anybody know if I can invoke static events within unity editor?
This is the editor menu:

As you can see in the image below, currently my player is being loaded separately from the scene, which makes it impossible to invoke some methods.
Screenshot of hierarchy during play mode:

My intention was to unlock player abilities one by one, using a simple trigger pick up system. Kind of like upgrades from hollow knight, but at the moment I am not able to come up with any worthy solutions.
I'm still pretty new to game development, so I couldn't really come up with anything that could potentially solve my problem.

no not directly .. you can have a wrapper component on that object that has an instance method which you can reference in the event and which then calls a static method ... However, I suppose a proper dependency management would be better in the long run

thank you, now that I know it's not really possible I'll try to think of something else
